# A bit complicated 20 card games

Tags: mathematics, strategy, optimization

In the game of 20-card games, the objective is to select a card or pass on it at every turn, with the goal of maximizing the sum of the numbers on the chosen cards. You have knowledge of the numbers on all cards for the entire game and We know the order in which they will appear. However, there is one rule to keep in mind: **if you choose four cards in consecutive turns, you must pass on the following two cards.** This is the only rule in the game.

The numbers will come in this order:

$5,3,5,4,8,7,6,6,10,15,13,14,15,5,3,6,6,8,9,7$

To illustrate the rule more clearly, if you select 5, 3, 5, 4, then you must skip the next two cards, which are 8 and 7.

So,

> What is the highest possible total that can be obtained from these numbers and their arrangement with the given rule?

and the second question is that

> What is the highest possible total that can be obtained from these numbers if you play the game with the same 5 decks in a row with the same orders coming after and after?

For example,

**5,3,5,4**,8,7,6,6,10,15,13,14,15,5,3,6,6,8,9,7,**5,3,5,4**,8,7,6....,6,9,8,7.

in total 100 numbers.

Comment: Bonus Question should be posted as a separate, follow-up question.

Comment: I can't immediately see that there's a general non-bruteforce method to solving this, but that may just be my poor eyesight. Did you have a clever approach in mind, or is this intended as a programming exercise?

Comment: @Bass The dynamic programming approach I described could reasonably be computed by hand for $n=20$.

Comment: @Bass you do not have to solve by brute borce the first part at least. I believed this would be interesting problem for everyone since it requires different way of thinking (please check v2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $r_i$ be the reward for selecting card $i$.  You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether card $i$ is selected.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_i r_i x_i$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=i}^{i+3} x_j + x_{i+4} &\le 4 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\label1\\
\sum_{j=i}^{i+3} x_j + x_{i+5} &\le 4 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag2\label2\\
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces $\bigwedge_{j=i}^{i+3} x_j \implies \lnot x_{i+4}$,
and constraint \eqref{2} enforces $\bigwedge_{j=i}^{i+3} x_j \implies \lnot x_{i+5}$

For the $20$-card problem, the maximum is

> 125, achieved by selecting the following cards (1 = select, 0 = do not select)

> 11101110111011101111

For the $100$-card problem, the maximum is

> 600, achieved by

> 1110110111011101110111011101110111011011101110110111100110111011101101111001011101101110111011101111

---

Alternatively, you can use dynamic programming.  Let value function $V(i,k)$ be the maximum sum over cards $i,\dots,n$ if there are $k$ cards in the current run.  You want to compute $V(1,0)$.  The DP recursion is
$$V(i,k) = 
\begin{cases}
\max(r_i + V(i+1,k+1), V(i+1,0)) &\text{if $k < 3$}\\
\max(r_i + V(i+3,0),   V(i+1,0)) &\text{if $k = 3$}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Here's the resulting table of $V(i,k)$ values for $n=20$:
\begin{matrix}
i \backslash k  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\hline
1 & \color{red}{125} & 122 & 122 & 120 \\ 
2 & 120 & 120 & 117 & 117 \\ 
3 & 117 & 117 & 117 & 114 \\ 
4 & 114 & 112 & 112 & 112 \\ 
5 & 112 & 110 & 107 & 106 \\ 
6 & 106 & 104 & 102 & 99 \\ 
7 & 99 & 99 & 97 & 95 \\ 
8 & 95 & 93 & 93 & 91 \\ 
9 & 91 & 89 & 87 & 87 \\ 
10 & 87 & 81 & 79 & 77 \\ 
11 & 77 & 72 & 66 & 64 \\ 
12 & 64 & 64 & 59 & 53 \\ 
13 & 53 & 50 & 50 & 45 \\ 
14 & 38 & 38 & 35 & 35 \\ 
15 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 30 \\ 
16 & 30 & 30 & 30 & 30 \\ 
17 & 30 & 24 & 24 & 24 \\ 
18 & 24 & 24 & 17 & 16 \\ 
19 & 16 & 16 & 16 & 9 \\ 
20 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 \\ 
\end{matrix}

Comment: Thanks, especially dynamic programming part is very well done :)